# Javascript - get url parameter with hash

Tags: javascript

I try to get the URL parameter `ReturnUrl` which contains a hash:

```
http://localhost/Site?ReturnUrl=%2fPlace#/get
```

I use the code from
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

but it returns only `%2fPlace`. Why ?

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Answer (score 2):

While `location.search + location.hash` will return `?ReturnUrl=%2fPlace#/get` technically `#/get` is not part of the `ReturnUrl` parameter, it is interpreted by the browser as the fragment of the current url.

To handle this more correctly you should be url encoding the `#` as `%23` so the url would be `http://localhost/Site?ReturnUrl=%2fPlace%23%2fget`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the

```
"=([^&#]*)"
```

regex tag. Remove the hash tag, and add "location.hash" to your regex search and you should be set.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search + location.hash);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var ReturnUrl = getParameterByName('ReturnUrl');
document.write(ReturnUrl);
</script>
```